# Finding Acceptance Rate from Friend Requests

Tags: sql

Given two tables  `Friend_request (requester_id, sent_to_id , time)`  and  `Request_accepted (acceptor_id, requestor_id, time)` , find the overall acceptance rate of requests.

So my code/basic logic is the following:

```
select count(acceptor_id)/count(requester_id)
from Friend_Request left join Request_Accepted
on Friend_Request.sent_to_id = Request_Accepted.acceptor_id
where  Request_Accepted.acceptor_id is not null
```

Would that be correct?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? There is a handy tool like jsfiddle but for sql queries, which is conveniently called http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: You join the tables Friend_Request and Request_Accepted, but the where clause has the table Accepted.

Comment: @zoubida13: I don't have any data. It is a theoretical question.

Comment: @Damien I understand that but that's the whole point of the fiddle, you can create some dummy data and test it, which I thought would be helpful to you.

Comment: @Damien If my answer does not solve your problem, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In theory it would be almost correct.

```
SELECT count(ra.acceptor_id) / count(fr.requester_id)
FROM Friend_Request fr
LEFT JOIN Request_Accepted ra ON ra.acceptor_id = fr.sent_to_id
```

Just remove the WHERE because you want the rows will `NULL` acceptors from your `Request_Accepted` table. Otherwise it would be the same number divided by the same number.

Edit: Although you have to consider if they send multiple requests with one acceptance... then that's a different can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this question in a slightly different manner and thought I would share.

```
( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT requester_id, accepter_id)
  FROM request_accepted) / 
( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sender_id, send_to_id)
  FROM friend_request)
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess there would be a more efficient solution.

Since all the request actions are stored in the Friend_request table, and all the accept actions are stored in the Request_Accepted table, we can simply get the counts of each table and divide them to get the rate we need.

```
requests_count = select count(*) from Friend_request;
accepts_count = select count(*) from Request_Accepted;
accept_rate = accepts_count / requests_count;
```

In most of the databases, count(*) option do not need to scan all the records in the table, it is an O(1) option.